# SAMD21 or any other SAMx MCU : Pulse count in sleep mode

Tags: timer, microcontroller, sleep-mode, samd21

I have three external pins connected from the sensor to the SAMD21G18 MCU. 
The output of the sensor is voltage pulses on these three pins.
I want to count the number of pulses with the timers peripherals.
I want to count while sleeping.
I want to read the counts only after a certain time with the help of another timer generating the interrupt and waking up from the sleeping.

Has anyone tried to count while sleeping  (idle mode) on the SAMx MCUs?

Thanks a lot!